# In Acumatica, why is my JournalEntry extension delegate not firing?

Tags: customization, acumatica

In an Acumatica customization, I want to check journal entries after they are posted to see if they are being posted to a specific branch so I can create entries for another Tenant.

I am using the JournalEntry graph and creating a delegate on the ReleaseBatch method.

I know the extension is being hit because anytime I click anything on the Journal Entry screen, breakpoint on private bool testingExtensionIsActive = true; gets hit.
In order to get the code to compile I had to put the ReleaseBatchDelegate baseMethod before the bool unholdBatch = false parameter.  Optional parameters have to go at the end of the signature.  Normally the baseMethod goes at the end of the signature for the other delegates I have created.

I also tried another delegate just to see if I could get ANYTHING to work.  The second delegate in my code is for the PostGraph graph.  It has a simple signature so I thought that would rule out the issue I just describe above with the optional paramater.

I cannot hit the breakpoint set on string joe = "joe"; in either delegate.

...

```
public class JournalEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<JournalEntry>
{
    private bool testingExtensionIsActive = true;

    public delegate void ReleaseBatchDelegate(IList<Batch> list, IList<Batch> externalPostList, bool unholdBatch);
    public virtual void ReleaseBatch(IList<Batch> list, IList<Batch> externalPostList, ReleaseBatchDelegate baseMethod,
        bool unholdBatch = false)
    {
        string joe = "joe";

        baseMethod(list, externalPostList, unholdBatch);
    }
}


// Acuminator disable once PX1016 ExtensionDoesNotDeclareIsActiveMethod extension should be constantly active
public class PostGraph_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PostGraph>
{
    public delegate void PostBatchProcDelegate(Batch b);
    public virtual void PostBatchProc(Batch b, PostBatchProcDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        string joe = "joe";

        baseMethod(b);
    }
}
```

...

I confirmed I am using the correct graphs/methods as I am able to hit breakpoints in both methods I am trying to override.
This is the breakpoint in the ReleaseBatch method of the JournalEntry graph:

[image]

This is the breakpoint on the PostGraph method
[image]

What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override `ReleaseBatch` as it is a static method.
I recommend to review the `ReleaseBatchProc(Batch b, bool unholdBatch = false)` of the `PostGraph` class and try to override that one as it is a `public virtual` method.

```
public static void ReleaseBatch(IList<Batch> list)
{
    ReleaseBatch(list, null);
}

public static void ReleaseBatch(IList<Batch> list, IList<Batch> externalPostList)
{
    ReleaseBatch(list, externalPostList, false);
}
public static void ReleaseBatch(IList<Batch> list, IList<Batch> externalPostList, bool unholdBatch)
{
    PostGraph pg = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PostGraph>();

    bool doPost = (externalPostList == null);
    Batch batch = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        pg.Clear(PXClearOption.PreserveData);

        batch = list[i];
        pg.ReleaseBatchProc(batch, unholdBatch);

        if ((bool)batch.AutoReverse && pg.glsetup.Current.AutoRevOption == "R")
        {
            Batch copy = pg.ReverseBatchProc(batch);
            list.Add(copy);
        }

        if (pg.AutoPost)
        {
            if (doPost)
            {
                pg.PostBatchProc(batch);
            }
            else
            {
                externalPostList.Add(batch);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I left out [PXOverride].  How embarrassing.

This one works now.  The ReleaseBatch delegate doesn't work but that is due to a different issue.

```
public class PostGraph_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PostGraph>
{
    public delegate void PostBatchProcDelegate(Batch b);
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void PostBatchProc(Batch b, PostBatchProcDelegate baseMethod)
    {
```